# cant set selected value on select2 javascript ajax mode

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have a select2 element that load data from database using ajax. i want to load the value from db and select it as selected value in edit mode.
but im not able to load the value using trigger function.

i tried using looping by comparing selected values but i got the select2 option orinted twice.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var area = $('#area').select2({
            placeholder: "Pilih Cabang Area Tagih Collector Agency...",
            multiple: true,
            allowClear: true,
            width: 'resolve'
        });
        var k;
        var selected = [];
        //imloading the value from db and insert it into an array
        <?php foreach($area_coll as $area){
        ?>
            selected.push("<?php echo $area->group_branch_id;?>");
        <?php
        }?>

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>ama/c_agency/populate_dropdown_cabang",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                var html = '';
                var j;
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                //looping cabang
                for(j=0; j<data.length; j++){  
                    $('#area').append($('<option>').val(data[j].GroupBranchID).text(data[j].branch));
                }
            }
        });
//this function not working at all
        area.val(selected).trigger("change");
    });
```

im not getting any error with this code nor the value still not selected.

Comment: okay, i already have the solution, im using array includes function to check if printed option is in the selected array.

Answer (score 0):

Select2 have ajax options.
So I think you can use ajax directly as an options of select2 (reference: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#default-pre-selected-values)

The document said:

```
To provide default selections, you may include an <option> for each selection that contains the value and text that should be displayed:

<select class="js-example-data-ajax form-control">
  <option value="3620194" selected="selected">select2/select2</option>
</select>
```

Mean that at the options you can push `selected="selected"` at edit page when option is stored on exist record.
Hope it help. thanks